# AWS Glue: Access denied for accessing table with S3 source data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-glue

I have manually created a Glue table with S3 bucker as the source.

The S3 bucket has a bucket policy defined to allow access only from

- root
- my user_id
- or a role defined for Glue

Now when a different user who has AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess tries to access the table from Glue console he gets access denied although Glue has service access to the S3 bucket.

Request help in understanding this behavior.

Thanks

Comment: If your role for AWS Glue has privileges to these buckets everything should be ok. What error do you receive ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please look into the policy details of role "AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess"? Most probably its expecting the S3 bucket will have certain prefix e.g. "aws-glue-*". In that case either update your policy or rename your bucket to have aws-glue- prefix.

```
"Resource": [
 "arn:aws:s3:::aws-glue-*"
```